# Given the lenght of the hypotenus and the sum of the legs find the area of right triangle

Tags: geometry

Given: right-angled $\triangle ABC$, the length of the hypotenuse $c = 5$ and the sum of the legs $a+b = 6$. Find the area of the triangle.
I tried creating the following system $a+b = 6; a^2+b^2 =25$ however it got me nowhere, I get a really ugly quadratic equation .

Comment: Continue: so $(a+b)^2=36$, so $2ab=11$. In other words, the area $\frac{ab}{2}=\frac{11}{4}$

Comment: All you need is $\frac{1}{2}ab$ and $(ab)=((a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2))/2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\text{Area }&=\frac12ab\sin \angle C\\[3pt]
&=\frac12ab\sin\frac{\pi}2\\[3pt]
&=\frac12ab\\[3pt]
&=\frac14\left[(a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2)\right]\\[3pt]
&=\frac14(36-25)\\[3pt]
&=\frac{11}4
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Squaring $a+b$

$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$

Putting $a+b = 6; a^2+b^2 =25$

$\Rightarrow 36=25+2ab$

$\Rightarrow ab=11/2$

Area is half of $ab$ = $11/4$